# Convert int to CFString without CFStringCreateWithFormat

Tags: iphone, objective-c

The following is extremely slow for what I need.

```
CFStringCreateWithFormat(NULL, NULL, CFSTR("%d"), i);
```

Currently this takes 20,000ns in my tests to execute on my 3gs. Perhaps that sounds fast, but I can create and release two NSMutableDictionaries in the time this executes. My C is weak, but there must be something equivalent to `itoa` that I can use on IOS.

Comment: I think you can use itoa since you can use regular C in obj-c code. I might be wrong as itoa isn't available on all C libraries.

Comment: itoa is unfortunately not supported based upon the posts i've seen. This post says there is no itoa, but it does mention something called NumToString but I cannot find any documentation on how to use it and the example given is too poor. http://lists.apple.com/archives/carbon-development/2002/Aug/msg01198.html

Comment: Have you tried `snprintf()` and `CFStringCreateWithCString()`?

Comment: Could you have a look at my answer? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is the faster I can get:

```
CFStringRef TECFStringCreateWithInteger(NSInteger integer)
{
    size_t size = 21; // long enough for 64 bits integer
    char buffer[size];
    char *characters = buffer + size;

    *(--characters) = 0; // NULL-terminated string
    int sign = integer < 0 ? -1 : 1;

    do {
        *(--characters) = '0' + (integer % 10) * sign;
        integer /= 10;
    }
    while ( integer );

    if ( sign == -1 )
        *(--characters) = '-';

    return CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, characters, kCFStringEncodingASCII);
}
```