# What is the fastest way to convert a long long to NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I need to convert a lot of long long's to NSString.  What is the fastest way to do this?  I am aware of two ways to do this and I am wondering if there is anything else that would be faster.

```
NSString* str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld", val];
```

And

```
NSString* str = [[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:val] stringValue];
```

where val is a long long (64 bit int).  The first method has the small overhead of parsing the string and the second has the overhead of allocating an additional object.  Most likely NSNumber uses NSString's stringWithFormat, but I am not sure.

Does anyone know of a faster method for this?

Comment: how fast is it going with method 1 and how fast are you trying to get?

Comment: I don't think the difference is worth worrying about.

Comment: Do you need to have all the strings at once, or can you reuse a mutable string? Are you sure that this line is the performance problem?

Comment: Premature optimization? Do what's easy. If you later have a performance problem, use Instruments and see where the bottleneck is.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil

Comment: The fastest way is definitely *not* to ask on SO.

Comment: I am running instruments and there are some other areas of my app that need fixing.  This area showed up in the profiler because I am converting 1000's of numbers. I am not sure if there is much I can do about it, except to see if I can find a way to convert fewer numbers.

Comment: have you tried `itoa()` and then converting that to a NSString?  Not sure about speed, but it's another option.

Comment: @Putz1103 There is no `itoa` function in the iOS public SDK.

Comment: @rob Good to know.  You could still use the same idea though, just sprintf into a char array and then convert that char array to an NSString.  Again, likely not faster, but an option.  Or something more in depth like this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8568557/1671729.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put together a basic profiling app.  I tried your two approaches, and Rob Mayoff's two approaches.

`stringWithFormat:` took an average of **0.000008** seconds.  The other three approaches (calling `stringValue` on `numberWithLongLong:`), and Rob's two, all took an average of **0.000011** seconds.

Here's my code.  It's obviously not 100% accurate since there are a few other operations included in the profile, but the discrepancies will be the same in all of the tests:

```
- (void) startProfiling {
    self.startDate = [NSDate date];
}

- (NSTimeInterval) endProfiling {
    NSDate *endDate = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval time = [endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:self.startDate];
    self.startDate = nil;
    NSLog(@"seconds: %f", time);
    return time;
}

- (void)doTest:(id)sender {
    long long val = 1234567890987654321;

    NSTimeInterval totalTime = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        [self startProfiling];

        // change this line for each test
        NSString* str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld", val];

        totalTime += [self endProfiling];
    }

    NSLog(@"average time: %f", totalTime / 1000);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This is the fastest to type:

```
NSString *string = @(val).description;
```

This requires one additional keystroke:

```
NSString *string = @(val).stringValue;
```

If you mean the fastest at run time, the only way to be sure is to try it both ways and see.  **Profile.  Don't speculate.**

Comment: You should never use `description` for non-debug purposes.

Comment: Can you point me to the Apple documentation that says so?  Because I see that in the documentation for `debugDescription`, but not in the documentation for `description`.

Comment: @HotLicks While I agree with you there is one exception I guarantee you use - `NSString`.

Comment: Apparently the rule changed with iOS 5, probably because it was being so commonly ignored.