# Why some strings are shown with quotes in array and some without?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an array of strings but somehow when I log them some of them are in parenthesis and some are not.

Here is what I get when I log the array:

```
2013-12-21 21:01:00.756 bit[1910:907] Array after adding: (
    ash,
    "charline_de_luca",
    "chiara_ferragni"
)
```

Why first string is without quotes? I log them before adding to array and they are without quotes when I log them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strings containing only alpha-numeric character are displayed without quotes.

Comment: And the `description` method is for programmer's convenience, not for use as any kind of encoder of date for later decoding purposes.

Comment: Why is it this way? It only adds inconsistency.

Comment: Perhaps @bbum can answer. I assume this is due to legacy code.

Comment: @Dvole: The `description` method of NSArray and NSDictionary use the so-called "Old-Style ASCII Property Lists" format, which is documented here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/PropertyLists/OldStylePlists/OldStylePLists.html.

Comment: @bbum: About `description`: I also used to state that it can only be used for debugging purposes, but there is a little discussion about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20550645/1187415. Can you point to a definite reference?

Comment: @Martin, If i am wrong is it something like that the string which contains special character should displayed in quotes??

Comment: @MartinR NSString may be special cased?  I don't know. I'd need a link to the policy changing documentation.  Note that examples have frequently violated this rule.